# How to align an element to center without using margin or text-align

Tags: html, css

I have ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jCCL7/)):

```
<body>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav_left"><a class="nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_left"><a class="nav" href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="nav">
            <form class="nav" method="post" action="action.php?do=search">
                <input class="search_bar" type="text" name="search_input" />
            </form>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_right"><a class="nav" href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li class="nav_right"><a class="nav" href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

And I have:

```
html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:12px;}
body {background:#F1F1F1;}

#navbar {
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#34495e;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #222;
    text-align:center;
}
    ul.nav {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style-type:none;
    }
    li.nav_left, li.nav_right, li.nav {padding:0 5px;}
    li.nav_left {float:left;}
    li.nav_right {float:right;}
    li.nav {}
```

I would like to be able to align `li.nav` to the center without using text-align or margin as I have both `float:left` and `float:right` in use, so the `float:right` would be pushed out of line if they are used.

Hope you can help, thanks.

Comment: Using 1nsane's approach; how about [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCCL7/7/)?

Comment: akinuri, feel free to submit an answer explaining what you posted, and I'll mark it up for ya!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning:

```
html, body {height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;font-size:12px;}
body {background:#F1F1F1;}

#navbar {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;    
  padding:5px 0;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#34495e;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #222;
}

ul.nav {padding:0;list-style-type:none;}
li.nav_left, li.nav_right {padding:0 5px;}
li.nav_left {float:left;}
li.nav_right {float:right;}
li.nav {
  background-color:green;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;    
  margin:-15px 0 0 -100px;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

You need to rearrange your html code:

```
<body>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav_left"><a class="nav" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav_left"><a class="nav" href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="nav_right"><a class="nav" href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li class="nav_right"><a class="nav" href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li class="nav">
            <form class="nav" method="post" action="action.php?do=search">
                <input class="search_bar" type="text" name="search_input" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

The above code is positioning the LEFT side of li.nav in the middle of #navbar. By using half of the width of li.nav as negative margin, the entire element is positioned in the exact center.

Just a quick example how it could work. You could also make container elements around nav_left and and nav_right and use position:absolute there as well. Inside the container element you can use float for the nav_left and nav_right elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/jCCL7/5/

Comment: Doesn't work properly. `nav_left // nav_right` don't stick to one side of the page.

Comment: Hi there! It seems to be getting somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be centered, I'll have a mess around with the code sometime.

Comment: I have set li.nav to a fixed width and height now. The first value of margin (top) has to be half of the height value (negative), the fourth value of margin (left) has to be the half of the width value (also negative). Then it is exactly centered.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, it is a best to practice to use a "wrapper/container div".
Place all your div inside this wrapper div

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So your HTML structure should look (not necessary exact) like this.

```
  <body>
     <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="content">
             <p>"HelloWorld"</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
```

The code above will display all your HTML content on the center of your page.

Comment: I know how the general structure of a website should work.. But why would a full width nav bar go in a 960wide container